# Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access_token from server

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-oauth, keycloak

We are intermittently (and having a very hard time replicating it, except for one user) getting this error message while using Keycloak 3.3.0 Final. This is when attempting to authenticate using Google.

The stack trace is here:

```
org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:418)
        at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:334)
        at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:317)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor498.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:107)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:133)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:101)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The way we replicate this is by the user logging out of the application, going to log back in (at which point they notice it is taking a long time to authenticate), hit refresh and it brings them to a (keycloak) prompt asking for their user credentials. When they put these credentials in, it gives them the error, "We're sorry... Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider"

This is the error on the backend. It seems to be related to Oauth2 authentication.

I am guessing that something in the refresh process the user is attempting is causing an issue with the access token? Maybe the initial login is generating one but on refresh?

It's somewhat hard to debug this error very well because I have been unable to reproduce it on any of my devices, even when following the same workflow, and asking for the user's phone is.. unfeasible.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: I am going through exactly same issue and couldn't figure out a solution. Have you resolved this ?  Here is the link to the question I have raised https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430181/intermediate-authorization-request-not-found-error-with-spring-cloud-gateway-and

Answer (score 9):

Please check your `client_secret`.
I had a similar issue with Azure AD as an Identity provider, after changing client_secret all is working fine.

ref: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-March/017559.html

Comment: especially after importing a previously exported realm: the secret gets scrapped during export

Comment: But the OP said that this is happening "intermittently".  A misconfigured client secret would reliably fail.

Answer (score 3):

I know quite a bit about OpenIdConnect and how Google implemented it. I have no idea about Keycloak though.
I think what might be happening is that on the Keycloak side a cryptographic nonce is set for the OpenId authentication request to the Google server, which is something that most OIDC integrations do. The refresh then probably invalidates that nonce and so when the callback from Google to Keycloak occurs , Keycloak decides the callback does not contain the correct nonce and hence throws the error. Some implementations can survive a refresh though, but other implementations - like this one? - might not.

Would it be possible to debug the org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken method? I think that would be the best way to determine the exact cause of the problem.

If that is not possible it would be interesting to see with which parameters the callback at your own server is called. Could you find that in your access logs somewhere?

Comment: I should be able to look at both. I'll give you an idea of the workflow.

There's a keycloak server, where this error is being logged and where keycloak resides.

There's a mobile app, where the browser instance is integrated into, and that is connecting to keycloak via https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-ios-oauth2

Comment: Not necessarily the answer (haven't confirmed yet), but you're the only one that tried so I may as well award you the points as otherwise they'll expire