# Intermediate authorization_request_not_found error with Spring Cloud Gateway and Keycloak

Tags: session-cookies, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, session-timeout, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working on a microservice architecture developed in Spring boot with an API gateway service using Spring Cloud Gateway. I am using Keycloak as an identity provider. Everything is working fine normally, but I am getting intermediate **authorization_request_not_found** exception on user login and a whitelable error page occurs. **If we try again, it works.**

Below is the exception I received on Keycloak server:

```
[org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-264) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.keycloak.broker.provider.IdentityBrokerException: No access_token from server.
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.3//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.verifyAccessToken(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:495)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.3//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.OIDCIdentityProvider.getFederatedIdentity(OIDCIdentityProvider.java:360)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@9.0.3//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:472)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor938.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
    ... more stack trace
```

Below is the configuration code:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    favicon:
      enabled: false
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri : http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/certs
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: <client-id>
            client-secret: <client-secret>
            clientName: <client-name>
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            provider: keycloak
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope:
            - openid
            - profile
            - email
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<realm-name>
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 6000000
        response-timeout: 600s
        ssl:
          close-notify-read-timeout: 600s
          close-notify-flush-timeout: 600s
          handshake-timeout: 600s
        pool:
          acquire-timeout: 6000000
          type: fixed
          max-connections: 5000
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 100MB
      max-request-size: 100MB
```

Below is some part of my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Below is the stack trace of exception on Gateway server:

```
    2020-06-13 08:04:17.237 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [47e02fef] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/login/oauth2/code/keycloak?state=YpBEDGlrHg1-podfMyIrKp02WYVPDIMRu_59vuRqado%3D&session_state=e8f4736b-1985-4730-af00-f55b38edf44a&code=1050f391-8438-4c18-ba52-d343ed25aa1c.e8f4736b-1985-4730-af00-f55b38edf44a.5b3ba9ec-3da5-4549-aaa8-79cf360f1d6d"

    org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthorizationException: [authorization_request_not_found]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationTokenConverter.lambda$oauth2AuthorizationException$1(ServerOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationTokenConverter.java:82) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) [reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:207) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:389) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.subscribe(MonoSupplier.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:360) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:131) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.12.RELEASE]
        ... more stack trace.
```

[image]

**As far as I have seen, this error occurs when user session timeouts.**

I think the cookie is not getting deleted once the session is timeout. This issue never happens when the user logouts from the application.

**Is there any way I can auto delete the cookie when the session timeouts? Or can I redirect the to logout API when I receive I receive timeout error before the user routes to the login screen?**

I have visited several blogs and other stack overflow issues but I can't figure it out what's wrong in my configs.

Is there any way I can find out what is wrong ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!